# How to decide what initial values to use for optimization

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimization

So the problem is that we have a pile of histogram data, and we need to fit the data with three gaussian distribution and one exponential function. And my current code contains a initial condition of the fit given by the teacher: `p_init`. However, this particular initial condition only works for about 4/5 of the test data. How do I improve my current code to adapt to all the different data sets?

I want to try to use random numbers to fit the histogram data until success, but it hasn't worked well yet.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.optimize as opt

def hist_fit(hist):
    ret = np.array([100.,1.,0.05])
    xmin, xmax, xbinwidth = 0., 2., 0.02
    vx = np.linspace(xmin+xbinwidth/2,xmax-xbinwidth/2,100)
    vy = hist
    vyerr = vy**0.5

    def model(x, norm, mean, sigma, norm2, norm3, c0, c1):
        exponential = c1*np.exp(-x/c0)
        gaussian1 = norm*xbinwidth/(2.*np.pi)**0.5/sigma * \
                    np.exp(-0.5*((x-mean)/sigma)**2)
        gaussian2 = norm2*xbinwidth/(2.*np.pi)**0.5/(0.4) * \
                    np.exp(-0.5*((x-0.1)/0.4)**2)
        gaussian3 = norm3*xbinwidth/(2.*np.pi)**0.5/(0.2) * \
                    np.exp(-0.5*((x-0.7)/0.2)**2)
        return exponential + gaussian1 + gaussian2 + gaussian3

    def fcn(p):    
        expt = model(vx,p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3],p[4],p[5],p[6])
        delta = (vy-expt)/vyerr
        return (delta**2).sum()

    p_init = np.array([10**3.,1.,0.07,1000.,100.,2., 100.])    
    r = opt.minimize(fcn,p_init)
    ret[0] = r.x[0]
    ret[1] = r.x[1]
    ret[2] = r.x[2]
    return ret

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = np.load('hist_data.npy')
    idx = np.random.randint(50)
    ret = hist_fit(data[idx])

    print('Signal main Gaussian parameters:')
    print('Area: %.1f' % ret[0])
    print('Mean: %.4f' % ret[1])
    print('Sigma: %.4f' % ret[2])
    print('chi^2/ndf = %.2f' % (fcn(r.x)/(len(vy)-len(r.x))))

    xmin, xmax, xbinwidth = 0., 2., 0.02
    vx = np.linspace(xmin+xbinwidth/2,xmax-xbinwidth/2,100)
    vy = data[5]
    vyerr = vy**0.5

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6), dpi=80)
    plt.errorbar(vx, vy, vyerr, c='blue', fmt = '.')
    N,mu,sigma = ret[0],ret[1],ret[2]
    cx = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,500)
    cy = N*xbinwidth/(2.*np.pi)**0.5/sigma * np.exp(-0.5*((cx-mu)/sigma)**2)
    plt.plot(cx, cy, c='red',lw=2)
    plt.plot([xmin, xmax],[0.,0.],c='gray',lw=2)
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()
```

The code is expected to work for different histogram data sets.

Comment: I have tried using while loop and random numbers to deal with the situation, but the code somehow doesn't work and won't produce an output.

Comment: A while loop and random numbers might work but this is not efficient in my opinion. You should consider [basinhopping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.basinhopping.html#scipy.optimize.basinhopping), as it uses a random step to find the global minimum.

Comment: You should post a minimal working code example and consider giving an example of the data (`data = np.load('hist_data.npy')`), as with the current post, your issue is not reproducible.

Comment: Thanks for the remind, I will remember to post the test data set next time. And my problem have been fixed by changing the 'opt.minimize'  default method to 'Nelder-Mead'  and expanding the maximum iteration time to a number large enough(e.g. 1000000), then the fit will work right for all the cases.

Comment: If your maximum iterations value is large enough, then it should work. Depending on your problem, I suggest to use a callback function including a precision condition (if you have one) to terminate once the condition is satisfied. That way your solution will be faster.